# How to show jQueryUI Dialog Buttons after script has been run

Tags: php, jquery, user-interface

I have a jQueryUI Dialog popup, which executes our telnet commands to a device. I don't want the window to close accidentally while the commands are being sent.

Is there a way to only show the close button when my telnet script has been executed?

Tomorrow at work i can include my code as well.

Much thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure you can definitely do it.

Don't show the close button when the pop-up is initially opened, instead leave it as "`display:none;`" using the CSS.
Now after the telnet command has been executed, make it return some value to that jQuery function & then use that value to change the CSS of that close button to "`display:block;`".

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

On initially loading the Dialog:

```
$("#telnetdlg").dialog({ buttons: [] });
```

And then when the telnet command has completed:

```
$("#telnetdlg").dialog({ buttons : [ { text:"Close", click : function() { $(this).dialog("close"); } } ] };
```

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I will try that tomorrow and keep you posted.

Comment: Hi guys,I'm gonna start to play with this today, but i#m still a little confused about the method your suggesting:

My code:
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function()
 {                
  // Dialog Link
  $('#reset_tunnel').click(function()
  {                    
   var $dialog = jQuery.FrameDialog.create({url: 'http://surfline.com', loadingClass: 'loading-image', title: 'Reset Tunnel for <?php print $APN->getApn_Name(); ?>', width: 900, height: 600, autoOpen: false});
   $dialog.dialog('open');
   return false;
  });
 });
</script>